# whatever I do sqlalchemy wont commit to the database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

`Python`, `Sqlalchemy`, `Mysql 8` envronment.

I am using only raw sql select and execute commands(No ORM). I have queries across databases like `insert into db1.table1 select * from db2.table1`.

```
engine = create_engine(echo=True)
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=user_engine)
transacton = session.begin()
with session as session:
   session.execute("INSERT into db1.table1 select * from db2.tabe1")
   session.execute("INSERT into db1.table2 select * from db2.tabe2")
transacton.commit()
```

nothing gets commited to the database. in log i see engine.ROLLBACK after each statement

trial 2

```
engine = create_engine(echo=True)
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=user_engine)
transacton = session.begin()
session.execute("INSERT into db1.table1 select * from db2.tabe1")
session.execute("INSERT into db1.table2 select * from db2.tabe2")
transacton.commit()
```

no change. nothing commited.

```
engine = create_engine(echo=True)
transacton = engine.begin()
engine.execute("INSERT into db1.table1 select * from db2.tabe1")
engine.execute("INSERT into db1.table2 select * from db2.tabe2")
transacton.commit()
```

and

```
engine = create_engine(echo=True)
connection = engine.connect()
transacton = connection.begin()
connection .execute("INSERT into db1.table1 select * from db2.tabe1")
connection.execute("INSERT into db1.table2 select * from db2.tabe2")
transacton.commit()
```

nothing commited. now rollback is not seen in logs.

What could i be doing wrong here. Trying for few days now. Not an expert in sqlalchemy here.

The solution i had with isolation_level in comment also didnt work either. so after `isolation_level=none` begin/commit had no effect. the data gets updated to db after each statement. Another issue is after one block is `commited`, and issuing another `begin()` i get error saying a transaction already exists. Have no clue on what is happening here. The reason i chose sqlalchemy was that i read it takes care of connection pooling. also it allows named arguments for raw sql. Otherwise `mysqlconnector` and `MySQLdb` was working just fine. I hope I am missing something basic here.

Here even though I begin as `connection.begin()` explicitly. I see `implicit` in logs
11-02-2024 23:19:56 | INFO | COMMIT
11-02-2024 23:20:36 | INFO | BEGIN (implicit)
11-02-2024 23:20:44 | ERROR | ERROR: This connection has already initialized a SQLAlchemy Transaction() object via begin() or autobegin; can't call begin() here unless rollback() or commit() is called first.
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: is there an error message with any of the above trials ?

Comment: it was because  `isolation_level=None` was absent in `create_engine` function. everything goes as normal. without any errors. begins, commits but nothing happens if isolation is not set. Strange design choice in my openion. may be because of my lack of knowledge in the library. but  for a beginner things should default to normal behaviour  is what i think.

Comment: good work.  you should post this as an answer since it answered the question.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not doing `with Session.begin() as session:` or `with engine.begin() as conn:` as shown in the documentation?

Comment: yes. i have separate functions getting executed within a transaction. so `with` begin doesnt help here

Comment: Does each function have to run in it's own sub-transaction? Perhaps you could [edit] the question to make the requirement clearer.